# Reading float values; output comes as 0.00000

Tags: c, scanf

```
int potenz(float x[1001], float y[1001])
{
    int i;
    float c=0.0f,k=0.0f; 


    system("clear"); 

    printf("Wahl der Potenzfunktion der Form c * x^k\n");

    printf("Bitte geben sie den Koeffizienten c ein: ");
    scanf("%f",&c);

    printf("\nBitte geben sie den Exponenten k ein: ");
    scanf("%f",&k);


    printf("\nIhre Funktion: %f x^ %f\n",&c,&k);

}
```

The issue is pretty simple, here is a log of input/output:

```
Bitte geben sie den Koeffizienten c ein: 23.512

Bitte geben sie den Exponenten k ein: 5.1

Ihre Funktion: 0.000000 x^ 0.000000
```

any idea why it is doing that or how to avoid that?

Comment: You should not be passing the address of `c` and `k` to `printf`.  Just pass the values without the address-of operator.

Comment: Not related but why are you passing y and x as parameters. Its not even being used in the function!

Answer (score 5):

You're printing the addresses of the variables `c` and `k` instead of their contents. You should do this:

```
printf("\nIhre Funktion: %f x^ %f\n",c,k);
```

Answer (score 1):

For printf specify the variable, not the variable's address:

```
  printf("\nIhre Funktion: %f x^ %f\n",c,k);
                                       ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting the address of the floats not the floats themselves.  Try changing it to:

```
printf("\nIhre Funktion: %f x^ %f\n",c,k);
```